# Solve the ODE $y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}y=0$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider ODE $y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}y=0$.

I have found the values of the constant $n$ for that $y(x) = x ( \ln x)^n $ satisfies the ODE as $0$ or $1$. How do you calculate the general solution I'm unsure how to go about this?

Comment: did you forget an y ? in the equation ? Because otherwise it can be reduced to a first order equation by direct integration.

Comment: yes I did, its edited now

Comment: ok Then it's Cauchy Euler equation

Comment: Try to substitute in the equation $y=x^m$ you will get that $m=1$ is a solution your second solution is then $c_2x$

Comment: Yes, this is a Cauchy-Euler equation with, in the notation of the Wikipedia article, $a=-1,b=1$ so that the exponent $m$ satisfies $m^2-2m+1=0$ which has a repeated root of $m=1$. Thus following the Wikipedia article you have a general solution $c_1 x + c_2 x \ln(x)$; that $x \ln(x)$ solution can be found by reduction of order.

Comment: I subbed x^r in as y but I was confused as to how everything cancelled out to give you what r equaled

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $y=y(x)$ satisfies the ODE
$$x^2y''-xy'+y=0.$$
This is equivalent to the given ODE (except the additional property that it allows discussing the solutions that can be defined at $x=0$).

First let $z=\frac{y}{x}$.  Then
$$z'=\frac{y'}{x}-\frac{y}{x^2}$$
and
$$z''=\frac{y''}{x}-\frac{2y'}{x^2}+\frac{2y}{x^3}.$$
This shows that
$$z''+\frac{z'}{x}=\frac{y''}{x}-\frac{y'}{x^2}+\frac{y}{x^3}=\frac{1}{x^3}\left(x^2y''-xy'+y\right)=0.$$
Denote by $u=xz'$.  We get
$$u'=xz''+z'=x\left(z''+\frac{z'}{x}\right)=0.$$

Therefore $u=C$ for some constant $C$.  This proves that
$$z'=\frac{C}{x}.$$
Thus
$$z=C\ln|x|+D.$$
Unless $z$ is a constant function, we see that $z$ is only defined for $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.  Hence, $C$ is in fact not necessarily a constant, but a local constant.  That is, $C$ may take one value $C_-$ for $x\in(-\infty,0)$, and another value $C_+$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$.  Therefore, from $y=zx$, we conclude that either there exists a constant $D$ such that $$y=Dx$$ for every $x$, there are constants $C_+,C_-,D_+,D_-$., $$y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}C_+x\ln x+D_+x&\text{if }x>0,\\C_-x\ln(-x)+D_-x&\text{if }x<0.\end{array}\right.$$  (That is, in the second case, $y$ is defined only for $x\neq 0$.  Anyhow, you can consider the first case as a special case of the second case with $C_+=C_-=0$ and $D_+=D_-=D$.)

---

Here, I solved the original ODE
$$y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}=0,$$
but the OP edited the ODE.  Anyway, you can solve the ODE without guessing.

Let $z=y'$.  Then
$$z'-\frac{1}{x}z=-\frac{1}{x^2}.$$
Define $v=\frac{z}{x}$.  Therefore
$$v'=\frac{1}{x}\left(z'-\frac{1}{x}z\right)=\frac{1}{x}\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)=-\frac1{x^3}.$$
Hence
$$v=\frac{1}{2x^2}+2C$$
for some constant $C$.  That is
$$z=vx=\frac{1}{2x}+2Cx.$$
Note that $z$ is only defined for $x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$.  Hence, $C$ is in fact not necessarily a constant, but a local constant.  That is, $C$ may take one value $C_-$ for $x\in(-\infty,0)$, and another value $C_+$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$.  Therefore,
$$y=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\frac12\ln x+C_+x^2+D_+&\text{if }x>0,\\\frac12\ln(-x)+C_-x^2+D_-&\text{if }x<0.\end{array}\right.$$
for some constants $C_+,C_-,D_+,D_-$.

Answer (score 0):

This is Cauch-Euler's equation :

$$y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}y=0$$
$$x^2y''-xy'+y=0$$
Substitute $y=x^m$
$$x^m(m^2-2m+1)=0 \implies m=1$$
$$y_2=c_2x$$
$$y(x)=c_1x\ln x + c_2 x$$
You can also use reduction of order method since you already have a solution of the differential equation. Substitute : 
$$y(x)= v(x)x\ln x$$

**A more simple solution is to consider :**
$$y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}y=0$$
$$y''-(x^{-1}y'-x^{-2}y)=0$$
$$y''-\left (\frac y x\right)'=0$$
$$y'-\frac y x=K_1$$
$$\left (\frac y x \right)'=\frac {K_1} x$$
Integrate:
$$ \frac y x =K_1\ln x + K_2 \implies y(x)=x(K_1\ln x + K_2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply $$y''-x^{-1}y'+x^{-2}y=0$$ by $x^2$  to get $$x^2 y''-x y'+y=0$$

Let $y=x^k$ and plug in your equation to get $k=1$ so you have one solution which is $y=x$

To get a second solution let $y=ux$ and plug into your eqaution to get $$xu''+u'=0$$

Solve for $u$ to  get $u=\ln x$ which provides the solution $y=x\ln x$

Thus your general solution is $$ y= c_1x+c_2 x\ln x$$